# OCaml-ssl with Unix.select leads to read errors

Tags: ssl, select, ocaml

I’m using SSL for reading data from various remote services over secure websockets as follows: I create the socket, embed it in the SSL context and add the socket to the reading list for Unix.select. When the socket fires, I use Ssl.read to get the data.

4 services are working well. And with one I get Ssl.Read_error.Error_syscall: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0) after receiving each websocket frame (size ~5-6Kb). By the way, frames here are much bigger than on other services, but I’m not sure it’s the reason.

I ignore syscall errors (and most probably loose some data) because frames continue to arrive. Then, always after one minute I get Ssl.Read_error.Error_zero_return: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), which means the peer closed SSL socket for writing and I have to restart the process because no new data will be received from this socket.

Problem is perfectly reproducible. At the same time examples for this service and my own test implementation with Node.JS receive the data for hours without any problems.

I assume I do something wrong or setup socket/SSL too straightforward (see below).

Any help or ideas would be strongly appreciated.

```ml
let sock = Unix.socket PF_INET SOCK_STREAM 0 in
let laddr = Unix.inet_addr_of_string p.interface in
Unix.bind sock (ADDR_INET (laddr,0));
Unix.connect sock addr;
let (sock, res) =
let req = Bytes.of_string http_request in
if ssl then begin
  Ssl.init ();
  let ctx = create_context TLSv1_2 Client_context in
  let sock = Ssl.embed_socket sock ctx in
  Ssl.connect sock;
  (SslSock sock, (write sock req 0 http_request_len))
end else
  (UnixSock sock, (Unix.write sock req 0 http_request_len))
```

Answer (score 0):

WireShark did the trick: this “bad” service sends two websocket frames in one tcp packet where second frame has zero payload length. Naturally, my Websocket implementation improperly handled frames with zero payload which lead to missing of Ping frames and closing of TCP connection by remote server.